# Are airliner flight plans/routes preset?

Tags: flight-planning

KLM has 3 flights daily from BLQ to AMS.

How do all of the crews handle the flight plans? Do the make a plan for every flight every day or do they have a database in which preset and stored flight plans are available and are ready to be extracted?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Airlines have an own department that is solely responsible for their flights and flight plans: **Dispatch**. Since single airways can have different availability or just direction for different days or even times of the day, there will be a preset pool of routes for recurring flights, which can then be adapted for anything out of the ordinary, like NOTAMS, weather forecasts, operational requirements like airspace closure, etc...

The flight plan is usually submitted by the dispatchers and not the aircrew.

Answer (score 3):

Most airlines will have predefined plans, which can be modified as needed (for example when there are NOTAMs).
And newer aircraft may even have a standard list of plans preprogrammed in their FMCs, again modifiable of course.

Answer (score 3):

They are called company routes. They are customised for an airline and added to a section of the monthly Navigation Database the FMS manufacturer sells to each airline. Flight plans can also be uplinked by the airline operation center to the FMS. Both of these the pilot can select into the active/primary flight plan.